# Align positions of the text and image within a table

Tags: html, css

I have my html mark up something like this

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img width="100" height="140" title="battlefield" alt="battlefield" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" src="images/img-1.jpg">
        <h3>Battle Field dsvadv dsadhjkba dsakjdbsa</h3>
        <span class="price"><del><span class="amount">$&nbsp;67.00</span></del> <ins><span class="amount">$&nbsp;23.00</span></ins></span>
        <a href="#">Add to cart</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img width="100" height="140" title="battlefield" alt="battlefield" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" src="images/img-2.jpg">
        <h3>Battle Field </h3>
        <span class="price"><del><span class="amount">$&nbsp;67.00</span></del> <ins><span class="amount">$&nbsp;23.00</span></ins></span>
        <a href="#">Add to cart</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

and the css is like this

```
<style type="text/css">
table tr td {
  vertical-align: top;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100px;
}
td img {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
td h3 {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
td span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
}
td a {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
</style>
```

After this my layout is something like this

[image: current layout is like this]

but I want my layout should like this

[image: i want my layout in this type]

Please help me out.

**NOTE**

The title which is within `<h3>...</h3>` text length may be different in different products. So the price should come just below the title and the buttons should come in a straight row ie just bottom of the content just like the second reference image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...........***[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/ebB8dl04)***................

Hi now this **is possible throw css** as now you can create **two div** and used to `position` than **it's possible** and **define** your `tr height 100%`

now you can **write css** as like this

**Css**

```
table tr{
height:100%;
}
table tr td {
  vertical-align: top;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100px;
  height:100%;
}
td img {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
td h3 {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
td span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
}
td a {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}



.order{
position:relative;
  border:solid 1px red;
  height:100%;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
.add_to_cart{
background:yellow;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="order">
        <img width="100" height="140" title="battlefield" alt="battlefield" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f20d2122fec97d8544bdbb998f5da742?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
        <h3>Battle Field dsvadv dsadhjkba dsakjdbsa</h3>
        <span class="price"><del><span class="amount">$&nbsp;67.00</span></del> <ins><span class="amount">$&nbsp;23.00</span></ins></span>
        <a href="#" class="add_to_cart">Add to cart</a>
          </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="order">
        <img width="100" height="140" title="battlefield" alt="battlefield" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f20d2122fec97d8544bdbb998f5da742?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
        <h3>Battle Field </h3>
        <span class="price"><del><span class="amount">$&nbsp;67.00</span></del> <ins><span class="amount">$&nbsp;23.00</span></ins></span>
          <a href="#" class="add_to_cart">Add to cart</a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>


        <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="order">
        <img width="100" height="140" title="battlefield" alt="battlefield" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f20d2122fec97d8544bdbb998f5da742?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
        <h3>Battle Field dsvadv dsadhjkba dsakjdbsa</h3>
        <span class="price"><del><span class="amount">$&nbsp;67.00</span></del> <ins><span class="amount">$&nbsp;23.00</span></ins></span>
        <a href="#" class="add_to_cart">Add to cart</a>
          </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="order">
        <img width="100" height="140" title="battlefield" alt="battlefield" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f20d2122fec97d8544bdbb998f5da742?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
        <h3>Battle Field </h3>
        <span class="price"><del><span class="amount">$&nbsp;67.00</span></del> <ins><span class="amount">$&nbsp;23.00</span></ins></span>
          <a href="#" class="add_to_cart">Add to cart</a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

**[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/ebB8dl04)**

Answer (score 1):

Just create another `<tr>` and move the buttons into the `<tr>`.

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <img width="100" height="140" title="battlefield" alt="battlefield" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" src="y5g17.png">
    <h3>Battle Field dsvadv dsadhjkba dsakjdbsa</h3>
    <span class="price"><del><span class="amount">$&nbsp;67.00</span></del> <ins><span class="amount">$&nbsp;23.00</span></ins></span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <img width="100" height="140" title="battlefield" alt="battlefield" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" src="y5g17.png">
    <h3>Battle Field </h3>
    <span class="price"><del><span class="amount">$&nbsp;67.00</span></del> <ins><span class="amount">$&nbsp;23.00</span></ins></span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="#">Add to cart</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Add to cart</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is the easiest with your existing code.

Another way is to use `div's` instead of tables.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to split your content into multiple rows. All the images goes in the first row, the title in the second row, amount in the next row and so on.
Please refer the code below:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img width="100" height="140" title="battlefield" alt="battlefield" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" src="images/img-1.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>
        <img width="100" height="140" title="battlefield" alt="battlefield" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" src="images/img-2.jpg">
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <h3>Battle Field dsvadv dsadhjkba dsakjdbsa</h3>
    </td>
    <td>
        <h3>Battle Field </h3>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <span class="price"><del><span class="amount">$&nbsp;67.00</span></del> <ins><span class="amount">$&nbsp;23.00</span></ins></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="price"><del><span class="amount">$&nbsp;67.00</span></del> <ins><span class="amount">$&nbsp;23.00</span></ins></span>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="#">Add to cart</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#">Add to cart</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```